# cannot run nohup command in bash script

Tags: bash, terraform, nohup

I have a terraform file which creates an ec2 instance and runs a bash script inside of the instance to start a server. The command I use to start the server at the end of the bash script is:

```
nohup pm2 start app.config.js &
```

When i login to the instance I see that the entire srcipt has run successfully apart for this last line. Note that it does work if I type the command manually.

Not sure why this command fails. Any ideas appreciated.

(additional info on script)

```
# install pm2

sudo npm install -g pm2

# build

sudo npm install

echo "STARTING THE SERVER"
nohup pm2 start app.config.js &
echo $?
```

this returns the log:

```
aws_instance.web[0] (remote-exec): STARTING THE SERVER
aws_instance.web[0] (remote-exec): 0
aws_instance.web[0]: Creation complete after 2m29s [id=i-0c7d7475475149c71]
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You should add more lines from the original script. If the line is not run, maybe it is never reached?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be running this as a proper service using your init system? What happens if it exits for any reason? How do you handle logs? I'd strongly recommend taking a brief read of systemd unit files and then use those instead of this pattern.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i have a nohup.out file to show logs and it says that something is already running on port 3000 when the script is automated. but when manually typed the nohup.out file tells me the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect output also

```
nohup pm2 start app.config.js &> some_log_file &
```

&> - means all types of output

Comment: Thank you - tried this but output is not being logged as command is still not executing